# c++ templates, static methods and constructor

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

Following code crashes on(/after) the Food-destructor; as shown in the stack below;

```
6 operator delete()  0xb7e5f4bf 
5 std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy()  0xb7ec648b   
4 <symbol is not available> 0xb7ec64d0  
3 std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()  0xb7ec653e   
2 Food::~Food() Main.cpp:126 0x0804c33c 
1 main() Main.cpp:199 0x0804c288
```

The Food-ctor is never called but the destructor is? AFAICT things go haywire when resources of "string _text" are being freed, but I can't seem to understand why this is going wrong.
Obviously I could change "string _text" to "string* _text", but I'd rather understand why this goes wrong.

```
class Food {
private:
    string _text;
public:
    Food(){
        cout << "ctor Food" << endl;
    }
    Food(string name) {
        cout << "ctor Food: name=" << name << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Food() {
        cout << "dtor Food" << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Action {
public:
    static T eat(int i) {
        cout << "Eat: " << i << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto x = Action<Food>::eat(1);
}
```

Comment: Your program doesn't even compile for me because `static T eat(int i) ` is not return a `T` which it's supposed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is *undefined behavior*. You define a function (`eat`) as returning a type `T`, but you are not actually *returning* anything. This leads to the assignment being undefined.

Comment: right indeed. Replacing eat with:
    `static T eat(int i) {
        T instance(string("Appel"));
        cout << "Eat: " << i << endl;
        return instance;
    }`
Works perfectly.